# Sample test case with "JavaDatasetSuiteBase" is failing, spark-testing-base_2.11

Tags: java, apache-spark, junit4, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to create a sample test case as given all the required dependencies and junit framework with spark-java.

https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base

spark-testing-base 2.2

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleJavaDatasetTest extends JavaDatasetSuiteBase implements Serializable {

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("aws-crediting")    
            .config("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts" , "true")    
            .master("local")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
            .getOrCreate();

    @Test
    public void testEqualDataFrameWithItSelf() {    
        OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this);    
        List<BasicMagic> list = Arrays.asList(new BasicMagic("holden", 30),
                new BasicMagic("mahmoud", 23));
        Dataset<BasicMagic> dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(list, Encoders.bean(BasicMagic.class));
        assertDatasetEquals(dataset, dataset);
   }
}
```

and the error i am getting is below, but it seems the is issue is not with multiple contexts, coz I am using it at configuration.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:901)
com.nielsen.engineering.netsight.aws.test.SampleJavaDatasetTest.<init>(SampleJavaDatasetTest.java:28)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
```

Comment: `class JavaSuiteTestJunit extends JavaDatasetSuiteBase implements Serializable {
@Test
    public void testDatasets(){
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext().createDataset(myList, 
    Encoders.STRING()).toDF();
    List<String> myList2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    Dataset<Row> df2 = sqlContext().createDataset(myList2, Encoders.STRING()).toDF();
    assertDatasetEquals(df,df2);
    }
}`
Error while instantiating org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder

Comment: Can you use the recent version which is 0.3.3 to see if things got improved? Regarding the comment, can you edit your question and add the entire stack trace for the error?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Spark session? Can you not use what is provided by  `JavaDatasetSuiteBase `?

Comment: @Jacek Lasowski, I am using the testing base in maven central /com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base_2.11

Comment: @Alexandre Dupriez, I have disabled the sparksession creation and tried to run, failing with Hive 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':

Comment: if i run as administrator on windows:
`[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 2]17/10/23 09:47:53 ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 27, Column 87: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "com.nielsen.engineering.netsight.aws.test.BasicMagic(java.lang.String, double)"
/* 001 */ public java.lang.Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new SpecificSafeProjection(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create the SparkSession inside your junit. It is already created for you. If need it to use it you can call function

sqlContext().sparkSession();

to get it.